# A problem of systems of linear equations (very basic).

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

- **The exercise is**:

Wheat flour is packaged in a supermarket in bags of 2 kg, 5 kg and 12 kg. In September, 250 bags were used and 5500 kg of wheat flour were packed. In October, due to problems with the 12 kg bags, 50 more bags of 2 kg and 5 kg were used, so only 4250 kg of flour were packaged.

- **The goals to solve**:

a) How many bags of each type were used in September?

b) How many percent of the total flour packaged between September and October was made in 2 kg bags?

***Doubt**

I know how to do the process of reduction method but I do not know how to transform each sentence into equations to solve the problem.

1- "In a supermarket, wheat flour is packaged in bags of 2 kg, 5 kg and 12 kg." I guess it is: (2x + 5y + 12z = 0), but I'm not sure.

2- "In the month of September, 250 bags were used and 5500 kg of wheat flour were packed." I guess it is: (250 = 5500), but I'm not sure.

3- "In October due to problems with the 12 kg bags, 50 more 2 kg and 5 kg bags were used, so only 4250 kg of flour were packed." I guess it is: (50(2x) + 50(5y) = 4250), but I'm not sure.

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea about writing out equations in terms of $x,y,z$. What will help is being very specific about what each of these quantities are.

In the first part of your answer, you let $x$ be the number of 2kg bags, $y$ the number of 5kg bags and $z$ the number of 12kg bags. You want the total number of bags to be 250, which gives you the equation $x+y+z=250$.

When you are finding the total weight, you need to multiply the number of bags by the weight of each type, so in September you get $2x+5y+12z=5500$. See if you can make a similar equation for October and then use linear reduction to find the solutions.

P.S. As a general hint, always make sure any equation you want to solve makes sense. For example, $2x+5y+12z=0$ is not realistic here as that implies that you have zero of each bag. Similarly, you will never be able to solve the equation $250=5500$, so you need to think through how you approach the problem again.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer, do you know how to get the third equation i suppose is 2x+ 5y+ 0z= 4250

Comment: Exactly! Although I suppose more technically it is $2x+5y+12(0)$=4250, since we already know that $z=0$, not so much that the bags now weigh $0$kg, but the answer will be the same. Always make sure you're thinking about the equations actually *mean*, not just whether they give the right answer.